# How do I get Visual Studio 2015 RC to pick up the repositoryPath setting from my nuget.config?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015

We use a custom location for our packages folder which we specify in a nuget.config file in the same folder as our solution:

```
<settings>
<repositoryPath>..\..\lib\packages</repositoryPath>
</settings>
```

Visual Studio 2013 picks this up fine and the NuGet package manager installs packages into the specified folder, lists installed packages correctly, etc.

In Visual Studio 2015 RC the NuGet package manager pops up the "Some packages are missing from this solution, click here to restore" message and if I click the button it creates a new packages folder in the same folder as the solution rather than using the location specified in the nuget.config. Installing a completely new package also puts it into a packages folder under the solution folder rather than the specified one.

How do I get Visual Studio 2015 RC to respect the repository path specified in the nuget.config?

Comment: I would file a bug against NuGet - https://github.com/NuGet/Home

Answer (score 8):

Make sure your nuget.config is configured like this:

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\..\lib\packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thnx, fixed it for me :)

Comment: One thing to note is that Visual Studio 2015 seems to cache the setting. So if you change it, make sure you restart VS.

Answer (score 4):

I filed this bug with NuGet: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/626

A fix has been made but I'm not sure when it will be released.